# Issues while using sqlplus with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, sqlplus

I want to use sqlplus within ruby. Dont want to use any gems[bec I cannot get it installed on our servers without much help from other teams ..etc] and want to keep it very minimal.

I am trying something as simple as this in my ruby script:

```
 `rlwrap sqlplus user/pswd@host << EOF`

     `set serveroutput on;`
    `commit;`    #ERROR1: sh: commit: not found
     sql = "insert /*+ APPEND*/ INTO table(col1, col2) values (#{data[0]},#{data[1]});"
     `#{sql}`    #ERROR2: sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Can anyone help me with ERROR1 and ERROR2 above

Basically for  "commit: not found" I think its getting executed on shell rather than in sqlplus. However seems like "set serveroutput on" seems to execute fine !

For ERROR2, I am clueless. I also tried using escape slash for the "/" in the sql.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside Ruby code or a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, don't use SQL*Plus. Don't call a command-line utility from inside your script;  between the `ruby-oci8` gem and the `ruby-plsql` gem, you can do anything you could accomplish from within SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the errors is that you are sending each line to the shell individually.  If your entire statement was wrapped in a single pair of backticks, it *might* work.

But if you really are unable to install the proper gems, put the commands in a temporary file and tell sqlplus to execute that, eg:

```
require 'tempfile'
file = Tempfile.open(['test', '.sql'])
file.puts "set serveroutput on;"
file.puts "commit;"
file.puts "insert /*+ APPEND*/ INTO table(col1, col2) values (#{data[0]},#{data[1]});"
file.puts "exit;"  # needed or sqlplus will never return control to your script
file.close
output = `sqlplus user/pswd@host @#{file.path}`
file.unlink
```

You'll have to be very careful about:

- Quoting values (if using oci8/dbi you could use bind variables)
- Error handling.  If using ruby libraries, errors would raise exceptions.  Using sqlplus, you'll have to parse the output instead.  Yuck!

So it can be done but I highly recommend you jump through whatever hoops are required to get oci8 (and maybe ruby-DBI) installed properly :)

ps are you sure you want to commit before the insert?